# How can I get Portuguese characters in Python?

Tags: python, character-encoding

I'm working with Portuguese Language. The characters are looking weird. How can I fix this?

The code:

```
import feedparser
import random

# Vou definir os feeds
feeds_conf = [{"feedurl": "http://pplware.sapo.pt/feed/", "linktoourpage": "http://linktopage.com/gggg/"},
              {"feedurl": "http://pplware.sapo.pt/feed/", "linktoourpage": "http://linktopage.com/zzzz/"}]

# Vou escolher um feed ao acaso
feed_a_enviar = random.choice(feeds_conf)

d = feedparser.parse(feed_a_enviar["feedurl"])

i = range(10)

updates = []
for i in range(10):
    updates.append([{"url": feed_a_enviar["linktoourpage"], "msg": d.entries[i].summary + ", "}])


print updates
```

The output:

```
[[{'url': 'http://linktopage.com/zzzz/', 'msg': u'\u2026depois de instalar o sistema operativo? Apesar de ainda n\xe3o ser a vers\xe3o final (segundo o calend\xe1rio, est\xe1 hoje dispon\xedvel a vers\xe3o Beta), o Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal tem demonstrado ser um sistema operativo r\xe1pido, seguro e est\xe1vel segundo os testes que j\xe1 efectuamos. Com a adop\xe7\xe3o da interface Unity, parece-nos que o sistema \xe9 [...]<div style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/ubuntu_natty_thumb.jpg" /></div>, '}], [{'url': 'http://linktopage.com/zzzz/', 'msg': u'A Google anunciou hoje que passou a permitir aos utilizadores partilharem recomenda\xe7\xf5es com os outros utilizadores nos resultados de pesquisa do Google. O objectivo \xe9 disponibilizar a cada utilizador os resultados mais relevantes, o mais r\xe1pido poss\xedvel mas, \xe0 semelhan\xe7a das palavras nas p\xe1ginas de Internet, a relev\xe2ncia assenta tamb\xe9m nas rela\xe7\xf5es. Recentemente, a Google [...]<div style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/mais_1_2.jpg" /></div>, '}], [{'url': 'http://linktopage.com/zzzz/', 'msg': u'O Mac OS X tem uma particularidade que me agrada bastante: mostra ser um sistema operativo simples e at\xe9 despido de fun\xe7\xf5es, mas na verdade tem ferramentas que permitem nalguns cliques chegar a tudo o que precisamos. Um dos exemplos claros \xe9 o Automator. Seja l\xe1 o que for que pretende fazer neste sistema operativo, [...]<div style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/images2011/imagem_desktoday01_small.jpg" /></div>, '}], [{'url': 'http://linktopage.com/zzzz/', 'msg': u'Este artigo foi escrito pelo leitor Diogo Oliveira para o Pplware A barra de ferramentas do Windows Media Player n\xe3o \xe9 nada mais nada menos do que aquele mini-player que ficava alojado na barra de tarefas e que permite o controlo das m\xfasicas em reprodu\xe7\xe3o. Este mini-player estava presente na vers\xe3o 11, mas foi removido [...]<div style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/wmp_12_1.jpg" /></div>, '}], [{'url': 'http://linktopage.com/zzzz/', 'msg': u'Nesta semana cinematogr\xe1fica, o destaque vai para a estreia de &#8220;Sucker Punch \u2013 Mundo Surreal&#8221;, uma fantasia \xe9pica de ac\xe7\xe3o que nos apresenta a imagina\xe7\xe3o f\xe9rtil de uma jovem, cujos sonhos s\xe3o a \xfanica sa\xedda para sua dif\xedcil realidade num hosp\xedcio. Destaque ainda para a estreia do thriller de terror &#8220;Perigo \xe0 Espreita&#8221;, com Jeffrey [...]<div style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/images2011/cinema117/imagem_cinema117_01.jpg" /></div>, '}], [{'url': 'http://linktopage.com/zzzz/', 'msg': u'Por Carlos Rodrigues e Jos\xe9 Afonso para o PPLWARE O Processing \xe9 uma linguagem baseada em Java que existe desde 2001 e \xe9 bastante utilizada por artistas gr\xe1ficos. Inicialmente utilizada para auxiliar no ensino do b\xe1sico da programa\xe7\xe3o, rapidamente cresceu, suportando diversas plataformas (Windows, Mac Os X, Linux) e permitindo desenvolver aplica\xe7\xf5es de forma muito [...]<div style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/mobile_00_thumb.jpg" /></div>, '}], [{'url': 'http://linktopage.com/zzzz/', 'msg': u'Por SamC para o PPLWARE.COM As tags (ou metadados) contribu\xedram para que a experi\xeancia de utiliza\xe7\xe3o aumentasse bastante para quem utilizava formatos de m\xfasica digital como o MP3. Quando apareceram os primeiros leitores de MP3 recordo que era fant\xe1stico mostrar a algu\xe9m que no ecr\xe3 conseguia visualizar algumas informa\xe7\xf5es relativas \xe0 m\xfasica a ser reproduzida [...]<div style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/images2011/imagem_mptagthat01_small.jpg" /></div>, '}], [{'url': 'http://linktopage.com/zzzz/', 'msg': u'A menos de um m\xeas da disponibiliza\xe7\xe3o da vers\xe3o final do Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal (28 de Abril de 2011), s\xe3o muitas as novidades j\xe1 conhecidas. Ontem, no seguimento de um artigo que li sobre a possibilidade de testar aplica\xe7\xf5es para Android sem as instalar, decidi investigar se havia o mesmo \u201csistema\u201d para o Ubuntu. [...]<div style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/usc_000_thumb.jpg" /></div>, '}], [{'url': 'http://linktopage.com/zzzz/', 'msg': u'Conhecer o nosso PC e o que por l\xe1 temos instalado \xe9 uma necessidade constante. Ao termos esta informa\xe7\xe3o conseguimos estar mais atentos a poss\xedveis problemas e nessas situa\xe7\xf5es conseguimos reagir de forma mais r\xe1pida e precisa. N\xe3o \xe9 no entanto simples ter acesso a toda a informa\xe7\xe3o de forma r\xe1pida e mesmo esta est\xe1 [...]<div style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/SYS-Informer_1_small.jpg" /></div>, '}], [{'url': 'http://linktopage.com/zzzz/', 'msg': u'Num passado recente o Pplware lan\xe7ou aqui um artigo sobre as Drives SSDNow V100 da Kingston. Agora, a Kingston revela que foi descoberta uma poss\xedvel falha t\xe9cnica com as essas mesmas drives SSDNow V100. Uma pequena percentagem destas drives tem dado origem a um erro no arranque da BIOS n\xe3o permitindo que o computador inicie. [...]<div style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Kingston-SSDNow-V+100-e1288714523877.jpg" /></div>, '}]]
```

For example, this:

```
"vers\xe3o"
```

should be

```
"versão"
```

How can I get the output in the correct encoding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is "it depends on where your output is going to":

`feedparser` is very smart. It already decodes the input and returns decoded unicode objects to you.

So you don't have to do anything. `u"vers\xe3o"` is already the decoded unicode object.

Your issue is that, when you print the entire list, you get the **representation** of the list contents. It's a way for python to show you what's in the string. `u'\xe3'` **is a representation of the correct *`ã`* unicode character** - That's just the python way of showing it to you, the programmer; The correct character is stored in the unicode object. Think of "printing representations" as debugging information;

If you want to show the real character, you must **encode** it to the output media encoding.

Example:

If you're showing that in a webpage, you must encode it to that webpage's encoding. If you're showing that on a terminal screen, you must encode it to that terminal's encoding.

My terminal is configured to use utf-8 as encoding, so if I do:

```
print u"vers\xe3o".encode('utf-8')
```

That prints the correct character on my terminal.

Note that you must *encode* to the ***destination** device encoding*. The encoding from the source is already decoded by feedparser.

---

## Brazilian Portuguese Translation

A resposta é: "depende de pra onde a sua saída está indo"

`feedparser` é muito bom. Ele decodifica a entrada e retorna objetos unicode já decodificados para você.

Portanto você não precisa fazer nada. `u"vers\xe3o"` já é um objeto unicode decodificado.

O seu problema é que, quando você imprime a lista inteira, você vê a **representação** do conteúdo da lista. É um jeito do python te mostrar o que está na string. `u'\xe3'` **é uma representação do caracter unicode correto *`ã`*** - Este é o jeito do python mostrar para você, programador, o conteúdo do objeto unicode. O caracter correto está lá dentro; Sugiro tratar "imprimir representações" como informações de debug;

Se você quer mostrar o verdadeiro caracter, você precisa **encodificar** o objeto usando o encoding da mídia em que vai mostrar o caracter.

Examplo:

Se estiver mostrando em uma página da web, você precisa encodificar o objeto para o encoding da página; Se você estiver mostrando em uma tela de terminal, você precisa encodificar o objeto para o encoding do seu terminal.

Meu terminal está configurado para usar utf-8 como encoding, então se eu fizer:

```
print u"vers\xe3o".encode('utf-8')
```

Isso vai imprimir o caracter correto no meu terminal.

Repare que você precisa *encodificar* para o *encoding de **destino***. O encoding feito na origem do feed já foi decodificado pelo `feedparser`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also the translation to portuguese. Obrigado.