# Python: Write text with accent marks to a file

Tags: python, file, unicode, encoding

I'm coding a twitter Event Detector and at the end of the detection I want to save the results on a .txt file. As the tweets are written in Spanish, some words of the result may contain accent marks, and I'm having some problems trying to save them as they should.

```
def save_event(self, event, event_counter, output_file):
    saving_data = {}
    saving_data['_id'] = event_counter
    saving_data['main_words'] = event[2].split(', ')
    saving_data['related_words'] = [None] * len(event[3])
    related_words_loop = 0
    for related_word, weight in event[3]: # En la posicion 3 del array event se guarda la lista de palabras relacionadas
        word_json = {}
        word_json['word'] = related_word
        formatted_weight = float("{0:.2f}".format(weight)) # Formateamos el peso a un decimal de dos digitos
        word_json['weight'] = formatted_weight
        saving_data['related_words'][related_words_loop] = word_json
        related_words_loop += 1

    saving_json = json.dumps(saving_data)
    with open(output_file, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(saving_json)
        f.write('\n')

def save_events(self, output_file):
    try:
        os.remove(output_file)
    except OSError:
        pass
    event_counter = 0
    for event in self.events:
        event_counter += 1
        self.save_event(event, event_counter, output_file)
```

I'm specifing the codification I want for the file on `with open(output_file, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:` and reading some other related questions this should work, but when I check the created file there are words which are saved like `\u00e9ranse` when they should appear like `éranse`.

Any idea if I'm missing anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python and string accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024442/python-and-string-accents)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is how you generate your json string:

```
saving_json = json.dumps(saving_data)
```

the default will have `ensure_ascii=True`. Set it to False will keep your non-ASCII characters as-is. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump